# Changes due to Chargeless Bosons

Tags: photons, momentum, bosons

Do chargeless bosons (i.e. Z boson and photon) change any properties in particles they interact with besides energy, momentum, and angular momentum/spin?

Comment: They don't; but the Z boson is the only such that interacts with neutrinos...